# Spring Boot Error handling for root context path

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, jersey

I am struggling to create error handling using jersey and spring boot for urls that do not match my defined prefix. See this setup:

application.properties:

```
server.contextPath=/mainstay
```

Starter:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Resource:

```
@Component
public class ResourceConfig extends org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig {

    public ResourceConfig() {
        register(HW.class);
    }


    @Path("test")
    public static class HW {

        @GET
        public String test() { 
            return "Hello test";
        }
    }
}
```

This will map the following URL for me:

```
curl localhost:8080/mainstay/test -v
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /mainstay/test HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 10
< Date: Mon, 13 Nov 2017 13:57:45 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
Hello test
```

This is fine, it correctly mapped my resource. Now, the error cases. Make this request:

```
curl localhost:8080/mainstay/test/does_not_exist -v
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /mainstay/test/does_not_exist HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Language: en
< Content-Length: 1078
< Date: Mon, 13 Nov 2017 13:58:21 GMT
< 
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found</title><style type="text/css">h1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Type</b> Status Report</p><p><b>Message</b> Not Found</p><p><b>Description</b> The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.</p><hr clas* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
s="line" /><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.5.23</h3></body></html>
```

This prints the default embedded tomcat error page as expected, however, now making this request:

```
curl localhost:8080/test/does_not_exist -v
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /test/does_not_exist HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Mon, 13 Nov 2017 13:58:54 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

This will not map to the correct error page. Frankly I have so far not found a way to even get a breakpoint to stop for a non-prefix request. This is because all the servlets (I believe) are registered with the prefix in mind, so there is simply no mapping to anything on the tomcat site.

I wonder if there is a way to catch the fact that a URL is not mapped with spring boot in order to react to the error correctly. In my actual application I am using jersey's exception mappers but they have the same issue. So even just throwing an exception I can catch will fix this.

I know I can remove the context path, this fixes my issue, but it is a bit annoying to have to go through all controller classes and manually manage the prefix.

I could redesign my code to use child-resources but that does also feel like quite a bit of effort for a simple case like this.

Thanks!

Comment: If this were Tomcat, I'd suggest something about configuring a global 404 error. I'd be really interested in hearing how you could do the same in Jersey.

Comment: This does not work either because using the context path doesn't ever route anything that doesn't match that. It literally looks like it is doing nothing if you hit a request beforehand. If you remove the context path you get to access the global 404 handler. If you configure your server to send the error code over the actual error, then you get to use the jersey mappers to catch the errors, same as with the global handler. The issue is that i can't seem to match anything that isn't at the very least my context path

Comment: This seems to be an oustanding tomcat issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11006#issuecomment-345144861